# degree 1 maps for bordism homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a degree 1 map between closed oriented manifolds.  Then the induced homomorphism between the homology groups is surjective up to torsion.

Can one say something similar about (oriented) bordisms?  For example, if $g\colon N\to Y$ represents a bordism class, then after perturbation, one can assume that $g$ is transverse to $f$.  Consider the preimage $f^{-1}(g(N))$ to find a submanifold $N'$ in $X$ of the same dimension as $N$.

Can one say anything regarding the class of $f|_{N'}\colon N'\to Y$ (ideally that it is equivalent to $g\colon N \to Y$?

Comment: The standard proof that a degree 1 map induces a surjection uses Poincaré duality; in fact you get a split surjection, and don't have to work mod torsion. This is right at the beginning of Browder's book, Surgery on Simply-Connected Manifolds. Bordism also satisfies a version of duality, see eg Conner-Floyd, Differentiable Period Maps. You could perhaps proceed in the same way.

Comment: Im on mobile, but For unoriented bordism there are stiefel whitney numbers for maps. They determine if a bordism class is null. This seems to be relevant here. A reference is conner and floyd’s differentiable periodic maps

Comment: Thank you very much for the references.  I'll look them up and see if I have enough knowledge to understand them.